# "No module named 'pysqlite2'" Error

Tags: 14.04, python, django, sqlite, pip

I am trying to run a server, but I get this error:

```
$ python manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Demo/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 33, in <module>
    from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as Database
ImportError: No module named 'pysqlite2'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Demo/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 35, in <module>
    from sqlite3 import dbapi2 as Database
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: No module named '_sqlite3'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/user/Demo/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/user/Demo/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/user/Demo/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 21, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/user/Demo/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/home/user/Demo/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/home/user/Demo/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/user/Demo/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 40, in <module>
    class Permission(models.Model):
  File "/home/user/Demo/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 122, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, **kwargs))
  File "/home/user/Demo/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 297, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/home/user/Demo/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 166, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/home/user/Demo/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 40, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/home/user/Demo/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 242, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/home/user/Demo/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 108, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/home/user/Demo/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/user/Demo/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 38, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading either pysqlite2 or sqlite3 modules (tried in that order): %s" % exc)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading either pysqlite2 or sqlite3 modules (tried in that order): No module named '_sqlite3'
```

and when I try to install Sqlite:

```
$ pip install sqlightCollecting sqlight
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement sqlight
  No distributions at all found for sqlight
```

What should I do?

Comment: Have you installed SQLite3? `sudo apt-get install sqlite3`

Comment: Try the solutions proposed in this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210664/no-module-named-sqlite3

Comment: @jos Yes it was installed: but now I am giving that error as well.

Comment: @SylvainPineau I've installed libsqlite3-dev as well

Comment: _sqlite3.so doesn't exist! in /usr/local -name _sqlite3.so

Comment: SQLight? Did you mean SQLite?

Comment: I found its problems eventually!!! the below solution in the answer section.

Answer (score 1):

I found the main problem! 
When I was installing virtualenv I didn't use root, so some files were missing.

When setting up your virtualenv, start a root shell

```
sudo -i
```

then you can run this command:

```
pip install virtualenv
```

By doing so, you can run Python3.4 and Django1.7 at the same time!

Alternatively, in my case:

Virtualenv was set by python3.4, and I think it's not synchronized with other versions.

I set virtualenv to use python2.7:

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
$ virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python
```

and this time, everything was OK.